# Methods Called from Lambda Cannot Access Fields?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have been experimenting with lambdas and have run into a problem I don't understand. The following code works fine in isolation, but somehow running this in a multi-threaded environment (that I don't control) causes `run()` to be in one instance and `doA()` to be in a different instance, which I can see as different instance IDs in the debugger.

```
public class Main {
    private String string;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Main main2 = new Main();
        main2.run();

    }

    private interface Stepper {
        boolean execute();
    }

    Stepper[] steps = { () -> { return doA(); }, () -> { return doB(); }, () -> { return doC(); } };

    public boolean doA() { System.out.println(string); return true; }
    public boolean doB() { System.out.println(string); string = "foo"; return true; }
    public boolean doC() { System.out.println(string); return true; }

    private void run() {
        string = "changed";
        for (Stepper step : steps) {
            if (step.execute() == false) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The real class implements a proprietary descendant of `Runnable`, which is not shown here. I moved the initialization of `steps` into the `run()` method, and it started working properly. How could having the array outside the `run()` method cause this?

Comment: You'll really need to post a reproducible example.

Comment: What fields? Please show us a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After reading more, I have a guess that the issue has something to do with method references. Earlier, my IDE was suggesting I replace the lambdas with method references, so perhaps the array was getting instantiated with some arbitrary `instance::doA`?

Comment: I'm lost. How is this code supposed to behave? What do you expect? How is it actually behaving?

Comment: This example runs properly (i.e., printing "changed", "changed", "foo"). In the multi-threaded environment, I would get a null pointer exception because the string was uninitialized inside the `doA()` method.

Comment: _multi-threaded_ how? What's invoked concurrently?

Comment: I have no idea what the calling code is doing to me. That's why I'm asking, "how can it be possible to get this result?"

Comment: `string` isn't `volatile`. One thread may have initialized it, but that won't be seen by another thread.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I'm unexpectedly seeing two instances that don't share the same instance value. My understanding is that the `volatile` keyword won't help across instances unless the field is a class static.

Comment: How many instances of `Main` do you have?

Comment: The real class is not called Main; that was the best I could extract out of the proprietary plugin environment. As I said, "[something] causes `run()` to be in one instance and `doA()` to be in a different instance. [ . . . ] How could having the array outside the run() method cause this?"

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense. What does _be in_ mean? Are you saying `run()` is being invoked on a different instance than `doA`? That means there is more than one instance of your class being instantiated. We'd have to understand how the instances are used.

Comment: Yes, invoked on. There shouldn't be multiple instances, but somehow there are. I want to understand how it's possible.

Comment: The last two sentences are ambiguous: Did you only move the initialization of `steps` into the `run()` method or also its declaration?

Comment: As it’s written here, it’s impossible. You may change the declaration of `steps` to `private final` but but any way, if you claim that there shouldn’t be multiple instances, you should start looking at who is calling the constructor (more than once) to find out where the instances are coming from. Still, as it’s written here, the instances for the lambda expressions are coupled to a particular instance.

Comment: I don't see how you can get NPE if `string` isn't initialized. If `string` is `null` then `println(string)` will just print `null`. My guess is you have a race condition. One thread constructs the instance, and the `steps` array is initialized at construction time. However, another thread calls `run()` which observes `steps` prior to initialization and thus gets NPE. A further hunch is that the newly constructed instance is handed off to the other thread in the superclass constructor, which is **unsafe publication** and which leads to problems like this. This is all guesswork on my part tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `Stepper` interface, you could do something like this:

```
public class Main {
    private String string;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Main main2 = new Main();
        main2.run();

    }

    private interface Stepper extends Function<Main, Boolean> {
        default boolean execute(Main main){
            return this.apply(main);
        }
    }

    Stepper[] steps = {Main::doA, Main::doB, Main::doC};

    public boolean doA() { System.out.println(string); return true; }
    public boolean doB() { System.out.println(string); string = "foo"; return true; }
    public boolean doC() { System.out.println(string); return true; }

    private void run() {
        string = "changed";
        for (Stepper step : steps) {
            if (step.execute(this) == false) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the method references are static, but passing in `this` to the execute function ensures that the current instance is always the one that will be acted upon.

If you've got a multithreaded environment, there's nothing stopping another thread from simultaneously running and interleaving with the output from this instance. I suggest that you gather your output into a `StringBuilder` and print it out as one operation to ensure that the output isn't interleaved. If the order's not important then fair enough, but it'll sure make debugging easier to know that each set of output is from the same thread. You might even consider appending the thread ID to your output lines.